# How to solve differential equation using power series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

$$x^3y'' + xy′ + 2y = 0 $$

Find a number $r \in \mathbb{R}$ and coefficients  $a_n$ such that $y(x) = x^r \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^n$ is a non-constant solution of the equation above. I am having trouble with this problem. I don't even know how to start. Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to differentiate a power series?

Comment: Also, for these type of problems, I've always seen $y=\sum a_nx^n$, are you sure you typed the question correctly?

Comment: @GFauxPas I asked him/her, if it was correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
x^3y''+xy'+2y&=0\\
x^3\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^{n+r}\right)''+x\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^{n+r}\right)'+2\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n x^{n+r}\right)&=0\\
\end{align}$$

Carry out the differentiation. Reindex any sums as needed so that you can combine them into a single sum grouping by $x^{n+r}$. Deduce what can be deduced.

Comment: I think he wanted a hint, not for you to do his homework for him :/

Comment: @GFauxPas Oh got carried away. They dropped the HW tag, so I forget sometimes.

Comment: I would have used $y = \sum a_n x^n$ in solving such a problem. Alex, can you guess why the assignment called for the exponent $n+r$?

Comment: @GFauxPas There is no solution that is a power series with nonnegative integer exponents. The only solution involves a value of $r$ such that the exponents on $x$ end up not being all natural numbers. $r$ might be $1/2$, $-5$, $\pi$, etc. And then you don't have something you can represent as $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$.

Comment: Can you tell by looking at the problem that that is the case?

Comment: @GFauxPas Sort of. The second derivative at $x=0$ quite possibly blows up based on what you see in the equation. So that is a clue that a plain old nonzero power series is not going to work (since such a series would have reined-in derivatives at $x=0$.)

Comment: The other answer is that if you recognize that for $r\not\in\mathbb{N}$, a series $x^r\sum a_nx^n$ is not equivalent to one of the form $\sum a_nx^n$, then you are allowing for a larger world of possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$0$ is an irregular singular point of this differential equation, so you don't get two linearly independent series solutions.  But there is one.

Substitute $y(x) = \sum_{n} a_j x^{r+n}$ into the DE and you'll get a relation betwen $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$.  Find $r$ so that for $n=-1$ this doesn't require an
$a_{-1}$ term.